# Is it possible to customize lightning:inputField displayed label?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, lightning-apps

In my lightning:recordEditForm I use [lightning:inputField](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_inputField.htm) which is mostly perfectly works. But I would like to customize displayed field label and make it different from object field label.

Maybe it's possible to replace lightning:inputField with any other lightning element having binding inplace?

Comment: You would need to write your own component using a variety of lightning:input, lightning:select, etc.

Answer (score 11):

You can use the lightning:inputfield variant of "label-hidden" along with a label tag to achieve this.

```
<label for="AddressState">State</label>
<lightning:inputfield aura:id="AddressState" fieldName="State" variant="label-hidden"/>
```

The default label will be hidden and the manual label shows in its place.

Comment: I cannot get this to work with `<lightning:inputfield`

Comment: `variant of "label-hidden"`  is for `<lightning:outputfield`

Comment: it works for lightning:inputField, but for some reason, it doesn't work if the field renders as a lookup

Comment: With LWC, the variant of "label-hidden" doesn't work with textArea types either.

Comment: The property `variant` is not documented for [`lightning:inputField`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:inputField/specification), so it might stop working at some point.

Comment: Thanks ```variant="label-hidden"``` also works for lightning-input (LWC).

Answer (score 8):

You would need to use this CSS to hide the default label

```
.THIS label.slds-form-element__label {
    display: none;
}
```

And then add your own custom labels:

```
<label for="AddressState">State</label>
<lightning:inputfield aura:id="AddressState" fieldName="State" variant="label-hidden"/>
```

Comment: This would mean you'd have to do labels for every lightning:inputField in your component.  I think you can add a class to your specific inputField and then do CSS based on that.